# Is such a Banach space $X$ isometrically isomorphic to a Hilbert space or not?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be a real or complex Banach space. $X$ satisfies:There exists real or complex series $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^n,\{b_k\}_{k=1}^n$ (which satisfies that:$\begin{cases} 
a_k,b_k\in \mathbb{R}\ \forall k=1,\dots n,\ \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k =\frac{1}{2},& X\text{ is a real banach space}\\ 
a_k,b_k\in \mathbb{C}\ \forall k=1,\dots n,\ \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \overline{b_k} =1,\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k =0,& X\text{ is a complex banach space}  
\end{cases} $) such that for any continuous linear functional $f$ on $X$, there exists $y_f\in X$ such that $\forall x\in X,f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a _k(\|x+b_{k}y_{f}\|^2-\|x\|^2-\|b_{k}y_{f}\|^2)$, then is X isometric isomorphic to a Hilbert space?

I ask this question to generalize a conclusion I found(a converse of Riesz representation theorem):

> ***Proposition.*** *For banach space $X$,if $X$ satisfies that $\forall f \in X^*,\exists y_f \ \text{s.t.} \ \forall x\in X,f(x)=[x,y_f]$,where
> $\begin{equation} [x,y_f]:= 
> \begin{cases} \frac{\|x+y_f\|^2-\|x-y_f\|^2}{4}& X\text{ is a real banach space}\\\\ 
> \frac{\|x+y_f\|^2-\|x-y_f\|^2+i\|x+iy_f\|^2-i\|x-iy_f\|^2}{4}& X\text{ is a complex banach space} \end{cases} 
> \end{equation}$(which is polarization identity in inner product space),
> then $X$ is isometric isomorphic to a Hilbert space.*

For those interested in the specific proof process,please *[click on this Chinese link](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/676306696?).*

My main idea in proving above proposition is:

> 1. Show that subset $M:=\{y_f:\forall f\in X^*\}$ is a subspace of $X$.
> 2. Prove that $M$ is an inner product space and is isometric isomorphic to $X^*$.
> 3. At this point, $X^*$ is a Hilbert space, so $X^*$ is reflexive, and $X$ is a banach space and thus reflexive, i.e., $X$ is isometrically isomorphic to the Hilbert space $X^{**}$.

But for the question I posed, I can't even prove that $M$ is a subspace of $X$.

```
                                                       --2024.02.07
```

---

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality-like inequality seems to be very important in proving *Proposition*, so maybe start with that:

[To what extent does the "Cauchy-Schwarz inequality" hold for a normed vector space not inner product space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4829030/986542)

```
                                                       --2024.02.18
```

---

Consider that $f(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$, We can take $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}(\|x+b_{k}y_{f}\|^2-\|x-b_{k}y_{f}\|^2)$ (maybe more convenience?).

```
                                                       --2024.02.28
```

Comment: Are you also assuming that every y in X is an $y_f$ for some f in $X^*$, that is [x,y] is  linear in x, for all $y\in X$?

Comment: The definition of M does not seem correct. Do you mean $M:=\{y_f: f\in X^*\}$ ?

Comment: @PietroMajer : No, I only assumed that [x,y] is linear for all $x\in X$.

Comment: @PietroMajer:What What I was trying to express is that M is the set consisting of the representation of each $f\in X^*$, and since $\forall f\in X^*,\exists y_f\in X,\ \text{s.t.} \ f(x)=[x,y_f]$, M is the set consisting of all such $y_f$, which would be in agreement with what you said, Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: You should explain what is meant by $a_kb_k$, $[x,y]$, $(X,{\mathbb R})$, $(X,{\mathbb C})$ (and what actually are $a_k$ and $b_k$).

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov I understand $a_k$ and $b_k$ are scalars, and $X=(X,\mathbb R)$ and $X=(X,\mathbb C)$ as: "$X$ is a real, resp. a complex Banach space"

Comment: @PietroMajer and $a_k$, $b_k$, are they numbers?

Comment: Yes, I think so, but maybe the OP should confirm :)

Comment: Pardon, I missed the definition of $[x,y]$.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov : Sorry for not using clear wording, I've amended the post to avoid confusion.